# ASP.Net MVC use javascript to post a model within a model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a small application that requires a login. The user must select the appropriate server to connect to from a dropdown list. On the post I am capturing the Username, Password, ServerId, and ServerName.

The Login model is setup as such:

```
string Username {get;set;}
string Password {get;set;}
Models.Server Server {get;set;}
```

The Server model:

```
int Id {get;set;}
string ODBCName{get;set;}
```

I am having trouble passing the Server model within the Login model on post. The asp method takes in a Login model.

```
public ActionResult Login(Models.Login login)
```

Creating the variable to pass on post in javascript:

```
var selectionId = $("#Server_ODBCName").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
var selectionText = $("#Server_ODBCName").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
var username = document.getElementById("Username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
var dataItem = {
            Username: username,
            Password: password,
            Server: {
                Id: selectionId,
                ODBCName: selectionText,
            }
        };
```

When the object is posted to the .net method the Username and Password are populated but the Server is null.

How can i pass the Server within the Login model so that server side model is populated correctly?

Comment: `Model Server {get;set;}` doesn't make any sense, unless you've named your Server model "Model" (which is weird). Please post your code completely.

Comment: Based on your correction it should work, the other thing that I could think of (in absence of complete code) is mismatch in datatype of ID and ODBCName between Javascript and C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use composite model. It is combination of two models.

1) Login
2) Server

Make one model LoginCompositeModel having both model in it,

```
namespace <Solution name>.Models
{
 public class LoginCompositeModel
 {
    public <login_tablename> loginmodel { get; set; }
    public <server_tablename> servermodel { get; set; }
 }
}
```

You can use model name instead of table name too.

Now talk about post in javascript, You can try ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: <url>,
  data: $('#<form-id>').serialize(),
  success: function(){
   //if want to redirect somewhere write in success call
   //or any other thing you want to do.
  },
  error: function(){
   alert("Unexpected error occured");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your property name in Javascript is `ODBCName` while in C# code it is `ServerName` first correct this typo.

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears you have an extra 'comma' after your ODBCName property. This third unintended property is probably causing the child object property to not be recognized as a Server object.

Also, you might try breaking down the building of your object in js:

```
var dataItem = {
        Username: username,
        Password: password
    };

dataItem.Server = {
            Id: selectionId,
            ODBCName: selectionText
        }
```